# When do you store ids and when do you store keys in gae datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

Suppose my datastore model looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Index
    private String email;
    private Long dateOfBirth;
    // More fields...
}

@Entity
public class Topic {

    @Id
    private Long id; 
    private String topicTitle;
    private Long date; 

}

@Entity
public class Comment {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Parent
    private Key<Topic> topicKey;
    private Long commenterId;
    private String text;
    private Long date;

}
```

Where the entity Comment has a parent entity Topic. I know one should store keys when specifying the `@Parent` such as I did in the Comment entity, but should one also store the key of the `commenterId`? Or is storing the `Long` id of that User enough?

Just wondering what the best practice is for storing references to other entities when they are not parents - should you store the id and generate the key later or just store the key to the entity. Is there a good reason why you might do one over the other?

EDIT: Since I am using Cloud Endpoints, the responses I get from my AppEngine project are JSON. Parameterized type of Key not allowed in the client libs. So for me, `id` can work and also `Key<?>` can work. Just note that you should return a websafe version of to your client using:

```
myKey.getString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically there is no reason to store a key as a reference. Keys take much more space - both in the datastore, and in objects that you transfer to and from the client.

Using a key may be necessary only if the same entity kind can be either by itself or a child of another entity. It is technically possible, and some data models can use this approach, although it is probably a very rare use case.

NB: I only use ID of a parent in objects - for the same reason (less space). In datastore entities parent ID can always be extracted from a child entity key. I use low-level Datastore API, however - you need to check how to correctly annotate child-parent relationship in the library that you use.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I use google app engine and in my example above, it appears GAE might be doing just what you said: extracts the parent ID from the child entity key when it stores entities.

Comment: Another question on a side note: For your various API methods, do you prefer to use an Entity as a parameter and get its ID inside the API method, or just pass in the relevant ID as a parameter? For example, would you do something like `insertComment(User user, Comment comment)` or `insertComment(@Named("userId")Long userId, Comment comment)`?

Comment: It depends :)  If I need more information from that entity and I already have it, I will pass it. If I don't have it yet, I will pass an ID and retrieve it inside the method.

Comment: I wanted to follow up on this question and ask you if you knew how much space a Key takes up in datastore vs an Id?

Comment: All keys are different as they consist of kinds and IDs/names, including all ancestors. I guess we are talking hundreds of bytes for a key vs 8 bytes for a ID, but a lot depends on the Datastore's internal implementation.